# Flexbox make two divs on left and third on right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to align divs, and I want to make both `postavatar` and `userinfo` in left side and `posttime` to be in the right.

```css
.postheader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.postheader .postavatar img {
  width: 90px;
}

.postheader .userinfo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.postheader .userinfo .postusername {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.postheader .posttime {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="postheader">
  <div class="postavatar"><img src="images/avatar01.png" alt="User Image"></div>
  <div class="userinfo">
    <div class="postfullname">Fahad Aldaferi</div>
    <div class="postusername">@Q8Xbox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="posttime">24 m</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply remove `justify-content: space-between;` from the flex container, and add `margin-left: auto;` on last flex item.

```css
.postheader {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
}

.postheader .postavatar img {
  width: 90px;
}

.postheader .userinfo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.postheader .userinfo .postusername {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.postheader .posttime {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  margin-left: auto; /*new*/
}
```

```html
<div class="postheader">
  <div class="postavatar"><img src="images/avatar01.png" alt="User Image"></div>
  <div class="userinfo">
    <div class="postfullname">Fahad Aldaferi</div>
    <div class="postusername">@Q8Xbox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="posttime">24 m</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `margin-left: auto;` on your `.posttime`, which will move the elements where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

One option: instead of `justify-content:space-between;`, use `justify-content:flex-start;`;  Then, on the time, use `flex-grow:1;` and `text-align:right;`

```css
.postheader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width:100%;
}

.postheader .postavatar img{
    width: 90px;
}

.postheader .userinfo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.postheader .userinfo .postusername {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

.postheader .posttime {
    color: #b3b3b3;
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="postheader">
        <div class="postavatar"><img src="images/avatar01.png" alt="User Image"></div>
        <div class="userinfo">
          <div class="postfullname">Fahad Aldaferi</div>
          <div class="postusername">@Q8Xbox</div>
        </div>
        <div class="posttime">24 m</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<div class="postavatar"><img src="images/avatar01.png" alt="User Image"></div>
```

inside

```
<div class="userinfo">
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to overcomplicate, just have everything you want on the left in its own div. Therefore, the flexbox will space that div (`.header-left`) and `post-time` apart from each other. You can of course use your own flexbox or other styles within `.header-left` to align those elements.

```css
.postheader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.postheader .postavatar img{
    width: 90px;
}

.postheader .userinfo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.postheader .userinfo .postusername {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

.postheader .posttime {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="postheader">
  <div class="header-left">
    <div class="postavatar"><img src="images/avatar01.png" alt="User Image"></div>
    <div class="userinfo">
      <div class="postfullname">Fahad Aldaferi</div>
      <div class="postusername">@Q8Xbox</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posttime">24 m</div>
</div>
```